# PayPal IPN Integration with Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

I am trying to set up a list that adds items when a PayPal Instant Payment Notification is received.

- PayPal IPN calls a webpage with POST values assigned that are then
  verified with a handshake.
- List item is generated based off the POST values and successful verification of the values

The issue that I am running into is the receiving url for the PayPal IPN call can not be setup for anonymous access. The page is requiring a log in and PayPal will not be able to pass the values because of this.

Has anyone successfully implemented PayPal IPN to create a list item in a secured list? Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem with SharePoint or with the PayPal IPN?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the receiver webpage is not publicly available. The site that is created for the receiver requires an O365 login and I have not found a way to bypass it.